# QWidget with border-image

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtstylesheets

I have my own widget (`MyWidget`, inherits `QWidget`) with the background (I use StyleSheet). In the main window, I want to add a few instances of `MyWidget`s. However, when adding promoted widgets from `MyWidget`, the background is lost, but the other formatting from css is preserved. I googled that `QWidget` ignores the background for optimization purposes, so in the `MyWidget` c-tor I call `setAttribute(Qt::WA_StyledBackground)`, but this does not affect.

How do I make widgets that are promoted from `MyWidget` keep the background?

Comment: Do you override paint method?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov, No, I did not override paint

Comment: What style do you use by default? Fusion?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov, I'm newbie, so I'm not sure. I did not change any styles.

Comment: Try to set Fusion style before customizing GUI. Or customize everything with QSS, not only single properties. QWidget will ignore background on modern windows themes, if you donlt specify border styles.